# Gallery thumbnail clicks not working

Tags: javascript, css

I put together the code for this website and the gallery functioned properly went testing the site ... but once it was uploaded to my web host - clicking on images no longer changes thmain one being viewed. I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

You can see it in action here: http://swampyankeebbq.com/about.html

HTML in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="photo_click/photo_click.css" />
<script src="photo_click/click_gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t01.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t02.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t03.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t04.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t05.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t06.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t07.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t08.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t09.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t10.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t11.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t12.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t13.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t14.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t15.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t16.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t17.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t18.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t19.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t20.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t21.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t22.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t23.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t24.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t25.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t26.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t27.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t28.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t29.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t30.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t31.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li><i><img src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t32.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
            <li class="click"><i><img class="default" src="http://swampyankeebbq.com/images/photos/t01.jpg" title="" alt="" /></i><span></span></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#gallery {width:580px; height:360px; position:relative;}
#gallery ul {list-style:none; padding:5px; margin:0; width:195px; float:right; height:219px; overflow:auto;}
#gallery ul li {display:inline; width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin:0 4px 4px 0; border:1px solid #444; cursor:pointer;}
#gallery ul li img {display:block; width:50px; height:50px;}
#gallery ul li span {display:none; position:absolute; left:340px; top:235px; width:200px;font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif; color:#06a; font-size:11px; line-height:15px; text-align:justify;}
#gallery ul li span b {color:#444;}

/* required for IE5.x and IE6 to display the start image size correctly */
#gallery ul li.click i img.default {margin:5px auto 0 auto; width:320px; height:240px; border:1px solid #fff;}

#gallery ul li.off {display:none;}

#gallery ul li.click {border-color:#fc0; background:#f8f8f8; cursor:default;}

#gallery ul li.click i {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:320px; height:355px;}

#gallery ul li.click i img {margin:5px auto 0 auto; width:auto; height:auto; border:1px solid #fff;}

#gallery ul li.click span {display:block;}
```

And the javascript:

```
clickMenu = function (menu) {
    var getEls = document.getElementById(menu).getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var getAgn = getEls;

    for (var i = 0; i < getEls.length; i++) {
        getEls[i].onclick = function () {
            for (var x = 0; x < getAgn.length; x++) {
                getAgn[x].className = getAgn[x].className.replace("click", "");
            }
            this.className += " click";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, could you add the code here instead of redirecting us to an external website?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Oops! New here ... I'll edit my original question.

Comment: In your site I see one JS file being included, but no other code that would use it.

Comment: Why do you place `img` tags inside `i` tags?

Comment: Inexcusable legacy code from copy/pasting from previous work ... no good reason.

Comment: Where have you bound the click event for the images?

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript ... I used the image gallery code available here: http://www.stunicholls.com/gallery/photo_click.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `clickMenu` function with the `id` of your gallery container element as an argument. 
Your current implementation does not call that function anywhere.

You could try doing that on body `onload`:

```
<body onload="clickMenu('gallery');">
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot - thank you! Unfortunately my step-father's (who's website this is) web host does not register code changes / file replacements very quickly - so it'll be a while until I know whether or not it worked on the live site.

Comment: No worries. Mark this as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Success! Thank you again - I REALLY appreciate it!